# Acquire/release семантика в С++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, атомарность

Почему применение acquire/release семантики к разным переменным в С++ ведёт к UB?

Насколько я понимаю данная модель памяти запрещает переупорядочивать read write операции.

Что тогда приводит к UB?

Comment: Если можно, поподробнее (лучше с примером кода и источником, который описывает это UB)

Comment: источник статья с хабра: https://habr.com/ru/amp/post/517918/ + насколько мне известно это взято из стандарта, применение данной модели памяти с разными переменными ведёт к UB

Comment: А разве store() с acquire правильно делать? Насколько я понимаю, acquire предназначен для load, а release для store. / Я прочел статью. Там все очень просто. Утверждается, что синхронизация при использовании release/acquire (логический порядок именно такой, т.е. сначала мы в одном потоке меняем значение переменной, а уже потом в другом потоке хотим прочесть ее новое значение) система должна (если сможет?) поддерживать синхронизацию именно по данной переменной. Поэтому, если сделать `a.store(10, release)` то это совершенно не гарантирует, что `b.load(acquire)` прочтет последнее изменение `b`

Comment: если я правильно понял ваш комментарий, то применение этой семантики на разных переменных не гарантирует, что поток, читающий переменную с acquire, запись которой не была произведена с release, синхронизирует память для данного объекта правильно, и другие потоки, выполняющие обращение к ней не смогут увидеть правильный порядок модификаций переменной, результатом чего является получение некорректных данных

Comment: и да, верно. acquire дает гарантию выполнения всех операций после того как будут выполнены все load операции до acquire fence, при этом оптимизации store операций допускаются. release же дает гарантию выполнения всех операций до того как будут выполнены store операции после release fence, при этом также оптимизация load операций допускается.

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли. Остается заметить, что для практических задач все это лучше вообще не трогать (вы никогда не сможете убедиться, что достаточно большая программа с такими штучками работает корректно). Применяйте грубые барьеры памяти в точках синхронизации, вынесенные в отдельно компилируемую функцию.